# Can't connect mysql docker to Drupal docker

Tags: mysql, docker, drupal

I'm following the instructions here https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal

I ran `$ docker run --name some-drupal -d drupal` just fine

and I ran

```
`docker run -d --name some-mysql --network some-network \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal \
    -e MYSQL_USER=user \
    -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
mysql:5.7`
```

just fine as well. But when I go through the drupal install script in the browser, when I get to the database connection. The connection throughs an error. I've tried user as the user and root as the user, either way I get this same error. Not sure if I need to connect more ports to the containers but The instruction make it sound like this should work. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Docker can only resolve containers hostname to each other when they are on the same custom network.

Your **mysql** container are in network `some-network` as you show here:

```sh
docker run -d --name some-mysql --network some-network ...
```

When you start the drupal container you'll need to do the same:

```sh
docker run --name some-drupal -d --network some-network drupal
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `docker-compose.yml` file with `Dockerfile`if needed.

For example, this is the contents of `docker-file.yml`:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
    SOME_DRUPAL_NAME:
        image: drupal
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:80
        depends_on:
            SOME_MYSQL_NAME
        environment:
            SOME_VARS: SOME_VALUE

    SOME_MYSQL_NAME:
        image: mysql
        restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somedrupal
       MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
       MYSQL_USER: drupal
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: SOME_NETWORK_NAME
volumes:
    SOME_NAME: {}
```

After having this file edited, run this command:

```
docker network create SOME_NETWORK_NAME
```

Also see Drupal environment variables for connecting Drupal to MySQL to add in `docker-compose.yml` file.

At last and when all things are done, run this:

```
docker-compose -f /to/your/docker-compose/file/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Or if you're in the same path as `docker-compose.yml`:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Then it should work.